# how to grab div with html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use html2canvas. I need to grab a specific div and add it to the body.

The code from official site works fine as a demonstration. But When I try to select my div, nothing happens.

Here's what's working

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  },
  width: 500,
  height: 500
});
```

and here's what's not working

```
html2canvas($("#div_name"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  },
  width: 500,
  height: 500
});
```

what am I doing wrong?
ty

up

```
 <div id="dsf" class="sdf">
   <%= render "share_form" %>
 </div>
```

up

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
html2canvas($("#dsf"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  }
});
</script>
```

if I use `document.body` it works both with or withour `$( document ).ready(function() {`

Comment: Did you try `$("#div_name")[0]` instead of `$("#div_name")`?

Comment: @movabo doesn't work

Comment: And did you try that without setting width and height?

Comment: @movabo, yes I did. nothing happens

Comment: could you post your HTML as well?

Comment: When are you executing your script? Directly on pageload?

Comment: @movabo yes. Just on top of the page I include script cdn and then the actual script inside document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```js
html2canvas(document.getElementById("div_name"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  },
  width: 500,
  height: 500
});
```

and make sure you have a div with an id of div_name

Comment: You are calling your div dsf but referencing div_name in the script. Per my answer you need to make sure you have a div with the same id as the one used in the script

Comment: that's just a fake name. I can't make a mistake in this

Comment: lol. it worked after I moved the script to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the script when the document is loaded.
So you have to replace

```
<script type="text/javascript">
html2canvas($("#dsf"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  }
});
</script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  html2canvas($("#dsf"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

(For more information see http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: plus one for trying to help but as I wrote in the update the document.body selector works with or without document ready.

Comment: oh, sorry, did see your comment just now.

Comment: Well, i guess it won't help you, but in this example (with similar markup) it works pretty well: http://jsfiddle.net/b3u2ergy/2/